# Find the saturday in the **first week**

Tags: php

I would find the  saturday in the **first week**  from this  month, do something

So if it is the  first week in a month and it is saturday {

echo Yes

else 
echo No

Thanks for comment

Comment: Please show your code

Comment: Question is totally unclear.

Comment: For best results, show what you tried and explain how that attempt failed. We can use your code as a starting point to provide a useful solution.

Comment: Check if today is a saturday and day <= 7?

Answer (score 0):

Just to make clear, what's unclear:

You should answer two questions:

- when does the week start
- what is the "first week"

If the week starts on Monday, let's assume, the first day of the month is Wednesday - is the "first week", the one, that started the previous month on Monday? In this case you would just be looking for the first Saturday in a month. Your wording seems to indicate that you didn't mean this simple case.

Or is it the first week that **starts** that month? In that case you would have to look for the first complete week (depending on when your week starts, Sunday or Monday) and take the Saturday of that week.

---

Ok, so you just want to know which calender week you are in and whether this is the first or second calendar week that is contained in that month.

This is basic functionality of the date function:
http://php.net/manual/de/function.date.php

You can either ask for the calendar week of a date directly, like this:

```
$week = date("W", strtotime("01.02.2015"));
```

Or you could calculate the first Monday from the offset it has from the starting weekday:

```
$weekday_of_first_day = date("w", strtotime("01.02.2015"));
```

This would give you 0 for a Sunday and so on. You then have to find the first Monday after that date, which would be the start of your second week.

Note the difference concerning "start of week": "W" assumes the week starts on Monday, "w" assumes Sunday.

2nd Edit:

Ok, here is the code:

```
<?php
// get current month and year
$current_my = date("m.Y");
// get first week of current month
$first_week = date("W", strtotime("01.$current_my"));
// trim the leading zero that is returned by date()
$first_week = ltrim($first_week, 0);

// get current week
$week = date("W");
$week = ltrim($week, 0);

// check, if it is the week after the first one
if ($week == $first_week +1) {
    echo "yes";
}
?>
```

To test this code for different month you will need the additional date parameter, that I omitted here.

Comment: Sorry my explanation was not good (poor english) i want the weeknumber  from the saturday on the second week  in a month, and i wont the weeknumber from the  first saturday in a month week start at monday .

Comment: If I understand you correctly the answer to my first question is: "The week starts on Monday".
Ok, but what is considered "first" or "second" week?

Comment: first is the first week in a month, maybe better::  the weeknumber from the first week in a month for februar 2015 is this weeknumber 5. The second weeknumber in a month is  in februar 2015 : weeknumber 6 , so no longer to speak about saturday but weeknumber.Sample:: Is it  the first  week in a month (sample week 5) , do something, is it the second week in a month  (sample weeknumber 6) do something

Comment: Thanks but is not wath i mean. litle sample :If it is the second week in the current month , echo yes . there  should no date in the code/ it must work for every month

Comment: Did you ever take a look at the date function? You should have noticed, that you can simply omit the date to use the current one.

Comment: Thanks ,,  i want to expand my question, but need a bigger field on this forum,  the same as you use for your code ? if i now edit the enter key the post is saved

Comment: Thank this is useful ,must play around with it.

Comment: To test this code for different month you will need the additional date parameter, that I omitted here. ???

Comment: No with the saturday, ...If it  is  the week with the first saturday in a mont...... Sample November 2015 , the first saturday is in week 44 , this is the second ? week in the month november

Comment: I don't understand what you are saying. Giving up.

Comment: Sorry , it is a language problem fo me. The code you  add above works fine for me, thanks for that....  i wont also: If  it is  the first saturday in a month , echo :Yes and sample  If  it is  the second  saturday in a month , echo :Yes